# Access Cloud Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have configured data gateway

I can publish Power BI reports now.

I tested it through my own account it is working

now, I asked other users to check reports and gave them this link

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/list/reports

but unfortunately non of them managed to get access, all have invalid password !!! and when they try to reset the password they got a message saying ***"password reset can only be done by the admin"***

not sure why is that!

do we have to add these users somewhere and configure them? if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want other people to see the reports you have built, you need to share the reports with these people via the Share functionality. Just giving them the URL to your workspace won't work.

Also, you need a Power BI Pro license to share reports or dashboards, and the people you invite to see your reports will also need Pro licenses to see the shared reports/dashboards.

For more detail try the documentation. [Ways to Share Your Work in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-how-to-collaborate-distribute-dashboards-reports)